# yq syntax to append a modified array element to a YAML file

Tags: yq

Given a YAML file like:

```
set:
  - x: a
    y: aaa
  - x: b
    y: bbb
  - x: a
    y: ccc
```

I want to select elements of `set` where `x==a`, manipulate them, and append the result to the original array. For example:

```
set:
  - x: a
    y: aaa
  - x: b
    y: bbb
  - x: a
    y: ccc
  - x: A
    y: aaa
  - x: A
    y: ccc
```

I found Mike Farah's version of `yq` and tried:

```
yq '{"set":[.set[], (.set[]|select(.x=="a")|.x="A")]}'
```

but this changes the original, resulting in:

```
set:
  - x: A
    y: aaa
  - x: b
    y: bbb
  - x: A
    y: ccc
  - x: A
    y: aaa
  - x: A
    y: ccc
```

Comment: kislyuk/yq produces expected result. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1214) to find out if this behaviour is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that my solution only worked for kislyuk/yq.

```sh
yq -y '.set += (.set | map(select(.x == "a") | .x = "A"))'
```

For mikefarah/yq go with @Fravadona's solution

```sh
yq '.set as $set | .set += ($set | map(select(.x=="a") | .x = "A"))'
```

Both output:

```yaml
set:
  - x: a
    y: aaa
  - x: b
    y: bbb
  - x: a
    y: ccc
  - x: A
    y: aaa
  - x: A
    y: ccc
```

Comment: You need to duplicate .set: `yq eval '.set as $set | .set += ($set | map(select(.x=="a") | .x = "A"))'`

Comment: Hmm, I thought the `map` was the magic sauce, but this seems to work: `yq '.set += [.set[]|select(.x=="a")|.x="A"]'`. So `+=` changes meaning of `.set[],` somehow

Comment: I was using mikefarah/yq `4.16.2`. Adding data based on the data itself is a pain with it...Sometimes there's an implicit copy and other times not...

Comment: @Fravadona You were right, my solution only worked properly for kislyuk/yq (with mikefarah/yq it modified the first elements as well). I have edited the anwser accordingly and included your solution for mikefarah/yq.

Comment: @pmf your kislyuk version seems fine with mikefarah v 4.25.1

Comment: @pmf is there a benefit to your `map` instead of my `[ ... ]` above?

Comment: @jhnc For arrays, in theory, `.set | map(…)` should be the same as  `[.set[] | …]`. But as we just saw, it sometimes isn't, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I opened [an issue on github](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1214). Mike identified the cause as:

> [yq] does not create a copy of the data structure when you call `.set[]`. In the expression where you use it twice, the elements of the splat refer to the same location in memory, so updating one updates both.
>
> To get what you need in yq, you need to explicitly make a copy, you can do that by merging it in to an empty node

His suggestion changes my code:

```
old: yq '{"set":[.set[], (    .set[] |select(.x=="a")|.x="A")]}'

new: yq '{"set":[.set[], (({}*.set[])|select(.x=="a")|.x="A")]}'
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Given that running kislyuk/yq on my original code produces the result I expected, I think the root cause of my problem is not having appropriate [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) for use of / assignment to `.set[]`.